# Get array from ui-router resolve containing two async calls within a loop

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angular-ui-router, angularfire

I am trying to get an array from a UI-Router resolve in AngularJS (using Firebase).

The array contains membership fees from different clubs. The clubs fees change at different times, so the correct fee for the particular point in time needs to be pushed to the array.

The clubs are iterated through in the for loop.

For each club:

First the time ranges are obtained for each club (asynchronously). Each time range is an object that shows the time over which there was a particular fee (date_active and date_ends). The time ranges are essentially an index for the other part of the database which contains the fees.

The correct time range for the current date is then found within the time ranges (synchronously).

The correct time range is then used to get the fee for that particular club for that particular time (asynchronously).

I am not sure how to structure my promises within this resolve function to ensure that the array of fees can be created and returned before the state is loaded.

I've deliberately left all $q promise handling absent from the code so it will be easier to insert by someone who knows better than me! It's the double async calls that are throwing me.

Thanks a lot!

```
.state('whatever')
    resolve: {
        'clubsResolve' : clubsResolve //Assume clubs have been loaded
        'feeResolve': feeResolve
    }


function feeResolve(clubs){

    var allFees = [];

    for(var i=0; i < clubs.length; i++){

        (function(i){

            var club = clubs[i];

            var timeRanges = $firebaseArray(db.child.('timeRanges').child(club.name));

            timeRanges.$loaded().then(function(){

                //I have omitted the details of this function
                var correctTimeRange = getCorrectTimeRange(timeRanges, new Date())

                var fee = $firebaseObject(db.child(club.name).child(correctTimeRange.date_active));

                fee.$loaded().then(function(){

                    allFees.push(fee);
                })
            })

        })(i);
    }

    return allFees;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the $q service in conjunction with a recursive function and resolve it when you have all the fee data.

```
.state('whatever')
resolve: {
    'clubsResolve' : clubsResolve //Assume clubs have been loaded
    'feeResolve': feeResolve
}


function feeResolve(clubs) {

    return $q((resolve, reject), function () {

        var allFees = [];

        function getClubFees(clubs) {
            var club = clubs[1];
            var timeRanges = $firebaseArray(db.child.('timeRanges').child(club.name));
            timeRanges.$loaded().then(
                function (timeRange) {
                    var fee = $firebaseObject(db.child(club.name).child(timeRange.date_active));
                    fee.$loaded().then(
                        function (fee) {
                            allFees.push(fee);
                            clubs.shift()
                            if (clubs.length) {
                                getClubFees(clubs)
                            }
                            else {
                                resolve(allFees)
                            }
                        },
                        function (error) {
                            reject('failed to get fee for ' + club + timeRange);
                        })
                },
                function (error) {
                    reject('failed to get fee for ' + club.name);
                })

        }
        getClubFees(clubs)
    })
```